# Communicating Via serial port with GSM modem

Tags: serial-port, gsm, modem, at-command, hyperterminal

I am using a EVB for siemens MC45 GSM modem. Itried to send At commands to it via serial port with Hyperterminal in windows (both Xp and 7). But the hyperterminal window is showing that I am connected but when I type something it doesnot show my writings. and no response from the GSM modem is received.

What Can I do ?

Comment: You can always look at this for reference... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54680885/how-to-communicate-with-serial-lte-modem-via-python-and-raspberry-pi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your hyper terminal settings when you are connecting with the modem.
Use these settings:  Baud rate:9600  data bits:8  stop bits:1  parity bits: none  flow control:none  Should work now. Also check whether you are communicating with the correct port

Answer (score 1):

Have you configured the hyperterminal session properly? I think you will probably need to set it up as follows:

- BaudRate 19200
- Databit 8
- No Parity
- Stopbit 1
- No Flow control